# How to use apache Gremlin constant in AWS Neptune database?

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

How to use apache gremlin `constant` in AWS Neptune database?

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').has('name', 'Thirumal1').coalesce(id(), constant("1"));
```

Not getting constant value in the output. The document says, need to use it with `sack` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-step-support.html. How to use constant in AWS Neptune.

Comment: Is the aim to return a 1 if the vertex does not exist? If so you need to use the `fold().coalesce()` pattern.  As written the query will end before the `coalesce` if the `has` returns no results.

Comment: Can you add it in the answer? It works!

Comment: Will do that now and add the full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to return a 1 if the vertex does not exist you need to use the `fold().coalesce()` pattern. As written in the question, the query will end before the `coalesce` if the `has` returns no results.

You could do something like this

```java
g.V().hasLabel('user').
      has('name', 'Thirumal1').
      fold().
      coalesce(unfold().id(), constant("1"))
```

In TinkerPop 3.6 a new `mergeV` step was added. Once database providers move up to that version, you will be able to use `mergeV` coupled with `onCreate` and `onMatch`.

**UPDATED 2023-03-17**

In TinkerPop release 3.6.0 two new steps `mergeV` and `mergeE` were added to Gremlin. These are designed to make the "create if not exist" or "upsert" type queries much easier to write. In most cases these new steps will replace the former `fold...coalesce` pattern. As of version 1.2.1.0 Amazon Neptune now supports the required TinkerPop version. For further reading please checkout the [TinkerPop documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#mergevertex-step)

Answer (score 0):

The coalesce() step returns the first option that returns a value. In your query example the id() step always returns a value so it will never return the constant("1").
The gremlin step support you refer to concerns pushdown of operations to the datastore. Fully down that page it is shown that really support is lacking for just a few gremlin steps.